# Mostrar un spinner de carga y deshabilitar los inputs y el boton con el que se hace la consulta

Tags: reactjs

Estoy tratando de implementar un spinner de carga luego de hacer una consulta a la api. Y a la vez deshabilitar los inputs de ese formulario y el boton. Me copie el codigo de los que hay en spinkit.
Que estaria haciendo mal hasta el momento? cuando hago submit me marca que el estado de loading se cambia a true y y dsp de 4 segundos vuelve a false. Y de yapa si alguien sabe tambien como se podria implementar esto para los casos donde hay problemas con el servidor y la respuesta va a tardar mas de 4 segundos. Gracias

Componente Spinner(el css esta bien linkeado)

```
import React from "react";
import "../Css/Spinner.css"

const Spinner = () => {
  return (
    <div className="sk-chase">
      <div className="sk-chase-dot"></div>
      <div className="sk-chase-dot"></div>
      <div className="sk-chase-dot"></div>
      <div className="sk-chase-dot"></div>
      <div className="sk-chase-dot"></div>
      <div className="sk-chase-dot"></div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Spinner;
```

FormularioLogin

```
  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault(); // previniendo el comportamiento por costumbre que tienen los formularios

    //Objeto que contiene la informacion que el endpoint necesita.
    const User = {
      userName: username,
      password,
    };

    //validacion del formulario

    //mandar a llamar la funcion del action que ejecutara el llamado a la api para hacer el login, pasandole el objeto User.
    loginUsuario(User);

    //mostrarSpinner()

    //resetendo los campos del input una vez que se ha hecho submit
    setUserInfo({
      username: "",
      password: "",
    });
  }

JSX
{loading ? <Spinner/> : null}
```

Authentication Action

```
 const loginUsuario = async (datos) => {
    try {
      //const respuesta = fetchClient("/api/account/login", datos)
      const headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token"),
      };

      const respuesta = await clienteAxios.post("/api/account/login", datos, {
        headers,
      });
      console.log(respuesta.data);
      Swal.fire("Correcto", "El usuario se logueo correctamente", "success");

      //jwt decode
      const decoded = jwt_decode(respuesta.data.token);
      console.log(decoded.unique_name);

      dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_EXITOSO,
        payload: {
          token: respuesta.data.token,
          userActive: decoded.unique_name,
        },
      });

      //usuarioAutenticado()
      history.push("/usuarios");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.response);
      ErroresLogin();
      dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_ERROR,
      });
    }
  };


 const mostrarSpinner = () => {
    dispatch({
      type: MOSTRAR_SPINNER,
      payload: true,
    });

    setTimeout(() => {
      dispatch({
        type: OCULTAR_SPINNER,
        payload: false,
      });
    }, 4000);
  };
```

Authentication Reducer

```
case MOSTRAR_SPINNER:
        return{
          ...state,
          loading: action.payload
        }
      case OCULTAR_SPINNER:
        return{
          ...state,
          loading: action.payload
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basado únicamente en este código, la propiedad `loading` de tu estado solo se modifica con la acción `MOSTRAR_SPINNER`, pero solo se disparaba con `mostrarSpinner()`. Lo que tendrías que hacer es despachar `MOSTRAR_SPINNER` justo al inicio de `loginUsuario` y `OCULTAR_SPINER` al final, de la siguiente manera:

```
const loginUsuario = dispatch => async (datos) => {
    dispatch({ type:MOSTRAR_SPINER });
    try {
      //const respuesta = fetchClient("/api/account/login", datos)
      const headers = {
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
        Authorization: "Bearer " + localStorage.getItem("token"),
      };

      const respuesta = await clienteAxios.post("/api/account/login", datos, {
        headers,
      });
      console.log(respuesta.data);
      Swal.fire("Correcto", "El usuario se logueo correctamente", "success");

      //jwt decode
      const decoded = jwt_decode(respuesta.data.token);
      console.log(decoded.unique_name);

      dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_EXITOSO,
        payload: {
          token: respuesta.data.token,
          userActive: decoded.unique_name,
        },
      });

      //usuarioAutenticado()
      history.push("/usuarios");
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.response);
      ErroresLogin();
      dispatch({
        type: LOGIN_ERROR,
      });
    }
    finally {
      dispatch({ type: OCULTAR_SPINNER });
    }
};
```

Para un cambio "estático" (la acción siempre hace el mismo cambio) no necesitas un payload, por eso no se los puse; sin embargo, tendrás que modificar tu reducer de la siguiente manera:

```
case MOSTRAR_SPINNER:
  return {
    ...state,
    loading: true
  };
case OCULTAR_SPINNER:
  return {
    ...state,
    loading: false
  };
```

Comment: Hola que tal. No me funciono. Solo me funciono cuando puse un state local en ese componente y llame a mostrar spinner ahi en esa funcion de formulario login. En lo que me pasaste vos, faltaria pasarle un payload en el caso de mostrar de true y en el caso de ocultar de false . Para asi en los reducers cambiar el estado y en base a eso mostrar el spinner. o estoy equivocado?

Comment: Ahi me funciono en cierta manera, igual si podes contestarme la pregunta anterior buenisimo. gracias

Comment: Para concluir, si me funciono. Tendria que arreglar otras cuestiones que no vienen al caso ahora. muchas gracias. cuando me contestes si podes la primera pregunta que te hice, ahi borro mi comentario.

Comment: Tienes razón, se me olvidó añadir el cambio al reducer. Agrego el cambio y puedes seleccionarla como respuesta 

Comment: muchas gracias che, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

el spinner se cierra a los 4 segundos porque hay `setTimeout` en el codigo, que hace que el dispatch para ocultar el spinner se cierre a los 4 segundos, se tendria que quitar ese `setTimeout` y llamarlo cuando el usuario se ha logueado correctamente.

```
    setTimeout(() => {
      dispatch({
        type: OCULTAR_SPINNER,
        payload: false,
      });
    }, 4000);
```

para que los inputs se deshabiliten, podrias poner el atributo `disabled` cuando `loading` sea `true`.

`<input type="text" value="" disabled={loading} />`

Comment: Hola. Gracias por tu respuesta. Sisi, me acabo de dar cuenta que me exprese mal arriba. A lo que quiero llegar es mostrar un spinner de carga hasta que se muestre el resultado del llamado a la api(sea cual sea su resultado). Ahora por como esta, ni siquiera se muestra el spinner, solo cambia el estado. Gracias por la data de los inputs.